# Two phase initialization deadlock: how to init class's properties before super.init() if you have to call self.someMethod() to init them?

Tags: swift

Confused with Swift's two-phase initialization.

- you should init all properties before `super.init()` call
- to initialize it you have to call some private method (this method is needed for reuse purposes and you don't want to bloat `init()` method also)
- to call your private method you have call `super.init()` first. Deadlock.

Here is example code that won't compile:

```
class A:NSObject {
    private var url1:URL
    private var url2:URL
    let settings:Dictionary<String, String>

    init(setting:Dictionary<String, String>) {
        self.configureAddresses()
        super.init()
    }

    private func configureAddresses() {
        /* ...some long and difficult reusable somewhere in this class configuration code... */
        self.url1 = URL(string:"result")!
        self.url2 = URL(string:"result")!
    }
}
```

p.s. i know i can assign stub values before `super.init()` call and then reconfigure them, but it will be too ugly if i have properties if non-trivial types like URL or my custom classes.

Comment: @Kamran thanks! i know this method also, but i always thought that force-unwrap it's a bad design and code smell...

Comment: @vadian Time to sleep!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

The given code suggests that the URLs are predefined with constants, so declare them directly

```
class A:NSObject {
    private var url1 = URL(string:"result")!
    private var url2 = URL(string:"result")!
```

**Option 2:**

The literal strings depend on another value for example in the dictionary then declare the variables lazily and as optional.

```
class A:NSObject {
       private lazy var url1 : URL? = {
           guard let result = settings["result"] as? String else { return nil }
           return URL(string: result)
       }()
```

In both options exchange the order in `init`

```
init(setting:Dictionary<String, String>) {
    super.init()
    self.configureAddresses()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Class A don't have this constants in its source file, and it gets them from dependency injection (for example), so option1 won't work. Option2 seems working. But do you think this is a nice way to use `optional` and `lazy`? Maybe my class design is bad and i should refact it but i think i have common init scenario...

Comment: If you can ensure that the keys in the dictionary always exist and the URL strings represent always valid URLs then you declare the properties non-optional and force unwrap them. The benefit of declaring properties lazily with a closure  is that the body is executed only once (unlike a regular computed property) and not until the property is used the first time. You cannot cheat the rule *You have to initialize all stored properties of this class before calling `super`*

Answer (score 0):

Another option, make your `configureAddresses()` a class method:

```
class A: NSObject {
    private var url1: URL
    private var url2: URL
    let settings: [String: String]

    init(setting: [String: String]) {
        self.settings = setting
        (self.url1, self.url2) = A.configureAddresses()
        super.init()
    }

    private static func configureAddresses() -> (URL, URL) {
        var result1: String = ""
        var result2: String = ""
        /* ...some long and difficult reusable somewhere in this class configuration code... */
        return (URL(string: result1)!, URL(string: result2)!)
    }
}
```

---

By the way, you should better know that **Always avoid Optionals is far worse than using Optionals properly**.

Comment: Actually is how i made it for now. If you could change class design what method would you recommend? You can make url1 and url2 optional but each time you access them you should do unwrap and handle error. And all this with knowing that class A in fact cannot work without this properties, i.e. in fact they are not optional.

Comment: @surfrider, if i were you, I would choose Implicitly Unwrapped Optional `URL!` as suggested by a comment. And this is one of the very few cases that I would use Implicitly Unwrapped Optional.